# How to invoke "put" method on Map using ReflectionAPI

Tags: java, reflection

```
Map map = new HashMap();
Method[] methods = map.getClass().getMethods();
Method method = map.getClass().getMethod("put");
```

I see method "put" in methods array, but I receive NoSuchMethodException for getMethod("put").

Why is it so and how can I have access to put method? I need to invoke it.

Comment: The method `Map#put` has parameters which you failed to specify when attempting to get the `Method`. Try `Map.class.getMethod("put", Object.class, Object.class)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To use [getMethod](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getMethod-java.lang.String-java.lang.Class...-), you must provide not just the name of the method you want to get, but also its argument types as `Class<?>` objects. Since you passed no argument types, it's looking for a method named `put` which accepts no arguments, but no such method exists; the `HashMap.put` method takes two arguments.

These work:

```java
Method m1 = String.class.getMethod("length");
Method m2 = List.class.getMethod("get", int.class);
Method m3 = HashMap.class.getMethod("put", Object.class, Object.class);
```

The `String.length` method takes no arguments, so no `Class<?>` arguments are needed in `getMethod`. On the other hand, the `List.get` method takes an `int` argument, so we need to pass `int.class` as an argument to `getMethod`.

Note that even though `HashMap<K,V>` is a generic class, the argument types are both `Object` because `K` and `V` are not real classes; they are type parameters with the upper bound `Object`. Hence, `getMethod` needs to  be called with two `Object.class` arguments.